# How to use a @ConstructorResult with a Set<SomeEnum> field

Tags: jpa, jpa-2.2

I'm trying to create a `@NamedNativeQuery` with a `@ConstructorResult` for a class that has a field with a `Set` of `enum` values.

VeterinarianJPA.java:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "veterinarians")
@Setter
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
@NamedNativeQueries({
        @NamedNativeQuery(
                name = VeterinarianJPA.FIND_ALL_VETS,
                query = "SELECT v.id, v.name, vs.specialisations " +
                        "FROM veterinarians v " +
                        "JOIN veterinarian_specialisations vs ON v.id = vs.vet_id",
                resultSetMapping = VeterinarianJPA.VETERINARIAN_RESULT_MAPPER
        )})
@SqlResultSetMappings({
        @SqlResultSetMapping(
                name = VeterinarianJPA.VETERINARIAN_RESULT_MAPPER,
                classes = @ConstructorResult(
                        targetClass = Veterinarian.class,
                        columns = {
                                @ColumnResult(name = "id", type = Long.class),
                                @ColumnResult(name = "name"),
                                @ColumnResult(name = "specialisations", type = Set.class)
                        }
                )
        )})
class VeterinarianJPA {

    static final String FIND_ALL_VETS = "net.kemitix.naolo.gateway.data.jpa.findAllVets";
    static final String VETERINARIAN_RESULT_MAPPER = "net.kemitix.naolo.gateway.data.jpa.Veterinarian";

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @ElementCollection
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @CollectionTable(
            name = "veterinarian_specialisations",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "vet_id")
    )
    private final Set<VetSpecialisation> specialisations = new HashSet<>();
}
```

Veterinarian.java:

```
public final class Veterinarian {

    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private Set<VetSpecialisation> specialisations;

    public Veterinarian() {
    }

    public Veterinarian(final long id,
                        final String name,
                        final Set<VetSpecialisation> specialisations) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.specialisations = new HashSet<>(specialisations);
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public Set<VetSpecialisation> getSpecialisations() {
        return new HashSet<>(specialisations);
    }

}
```

VetSpecialisation.java:

```
public enum VetSpecialisation {

    RADIOLOGY,
    DENTISTRY,
    SURGERY

}
```

When I attempt to execute the named query:

```
entityManager.createNamedQuery(VeterinarianJPA.FIND_ALL_VETS, Veterinarian.class)
             .getResultStream()
```

I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not locate appropriate constructor on class : net.kemitix.naolo.entities.Veterinarian

    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.ConstructorResultColumnProcessor.resolveConstructor(ConstructorResultColumnProcessor.java:92)
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.ConstructorResultColumnProcessor.performDiscovery(ConstructorResultColumnProcessor.java:45)
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.autoDiscoverTypes(CustomLoader.java:494)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:2213)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2169)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1930)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1892)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.scroll(Loader.java:2765)
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.scroll(CustomLoader.java:383)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.scrollCustomQuery(SessionImpl.java:2198)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.scroll(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:1058)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.NativeQueryImpl.doScroll(NativeQueryImpl.java:217)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.scroll(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1462)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.stream(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1486)
    at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultStream(Query.java:1110)
```

I expect that the SQL is returning multiple rows for a multi-valued `Set` rather than a single value, which is causing the constructor not to match. How do I change the SQL to produce the correct input to the constructor, or is there another configuration change I need to make?

Comment: What's the database type of vs.specialisations?

Comment: The `vs.specialisations` field is a `varchar(255)` from `@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I'm not sure if that's even possible in the way you want to to this. But you can use `LISTAGG` function on `specialisations` table to inline the `specialisations` with `veterinarians` by using some kind of separator.

So the query should look like this:

```
SELECT v.id, v.name 
(SELECT LISTAGG(vs.type, ';') 
  WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY vs.type) 
  FROM veterinarian_specialisations vs 
  WHERE vs.vet_id = v.id) specialisations
FROM veterinarians v;
```

The query will return veterinarian and his semicolon separated specialisations:

```
1   NAME   DENTISTRY;RADIOLOGY
```

And then in your `Veterinarian` class constructor you must remap String result back to Set of `VetSpecialisation`. I used Java 8 stream api just for convenience.

```
public final class Veterinarian {

private Long id;
private String name;
private Set<VetSpecialisation> specialisations;

public Veterinarian() {
}

public Veterinarian(final long id,
                    final String name,
                    final String specialisations) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.specialisations = Arrays.asList(specialisations.split(";"))
        .stream()
        .map(VetSpecialisation::valueOf) //Map string to VetSpecialisation enum.
        .collect(Collectors.toSet());
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  I'm using the H2 database which doesn't support the `LISTAGG()` function. I was able to use the equivalent: `GROUP_CONCAT(vs.specialisations SEPARATOR ';') specialisations`.

I was hoping that JPA would have had better support for `Set`s.

Comment: Having a set in a database field of varchar is an anti-pattern. That's why it's not supported by JPA.

Comment: @SimonMartinelli Do you have a link for this? I've not used JPA enough to see much discussion on any anti-patterns. I'd like to see the reasoning and any alternatives that were suggested. Thanks.

Comment: It's not JPA related. But SQL. Read this book: https://pragprog.com/book/bksqla/sql-antipatterns